# IPywidgets not displaying

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

[Pls look at this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arpbQ.png)

Hi, unable to view ipywidgets/ charts inline in the Jupyter Notebook with PySpark 3 kernel.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
 if (code_show){
 $('div.input').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.input').show();
 }
 code_show = !code_show
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Click here to toggle on/off the raw code."></form>''')
```

Here I'm trying to toggle on/off raw code.
But this is the output I'm getting

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

Comment: it would be more useful if you provided the code here, so others could easily test. do you not need to call display() around the HTML object?

Comment: Yes, have added code to the question.
I tried using the same code in my local machine, it works.
But when I tried on the Notebook on AWS server, it doesn't work.